# JavaScript fetching multiple known element IDs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning JS by making a character sheet (rpg), I got a form set up like this

```
<fieldset id="char-int">
  <label for="int">INT</label>
  <input id="int" name="int" placeholder="40" type="number" min="0" max="100">
  <input id="int-hard" name="int-hard" placeholder="20" type="number" min="0" max="100">
  <input id="int-extr" name="int-extr" placeholder="6" type="number" min="0" max="100">
</fieldset>
```

I need to change the value in ***int-hard*** and ***int-extr*** with simple rounded down division.

```
window.onchange  = changevalue;

function changevalue() {
  var hardRoll = document.getElementById("int").value / 2;
  var extrRoll = document.getElementById("int").value / 5;

  var setStat = document.getElementById("str-hard").value = Math.floor(hardRoll);
  var setStat = document.getElementById("str-extr").value = Math.floor(extrRoll);
```

This works, but there must be a smarter way to do this as I got multiple IDs I want to do the same stuff to like STR, DEX etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `id`s from your inputs and work within the context of your `fieldset`, like this:

```
<fieldset id="char-int">
  <label>
    INT
    <input name="int" placeholder="40" type="number" min="0" max="100">
  </label>
  <input name="int-hard" placeholder="20" type="number" min="0" max="100">
  <input name="int-extr" placeholder="6" type="number" min="0" max="100">
</fieldset>
```

```js
function changevalue() {
    var fieldset = document.getElementById("char-int");
    var intField = fieldset.querySelector('["name=int"]');
    var intHardField = fieldset.querySelector('["name=int-hard"]');
    var intExtrField = fieldset.querySelector('["name=int-extr"]');
    // ...
}
```

(Note that I also moved your `name="int"` field *into* the `label` so we don't have to use an `id` to link them.)

`querySelector` finds the first element within the element you call it on that matches the given CSS selector. (There's also `querySelectorAll`, which finds a list of all matching elements.)

Depending on how much you can parameterize the actual logic of the `changevalue` function, you could change the names to not have `int-` in them (or add classes), and then pass in the `id` of the fieldset (or the fieldset instance itself).

```
<fieldset id="char-int">
  <label>
    INT
    <input id="int-main" name="main" placeholder="40" type="number" min="0" max="100">
  </label>
  <input name="hard" placeholder="20" type="number" min="0" max="100">
  <input name="extr" placeholder="6" type="number" min="0" max="100">
</fieldset>
```

```js
function changevalue(fieldSetId) {
    var fieldset = document.getElementById(fieldSetId);
    var mainField = fieldset.querySelector('["name=main"]');
    var hardField = fieldset.querySelector('["name=hard"]');
    var extrField = fieldset.querySelector('["name=extr"]');
    // ...
}
```

QS and QSA are supported by all modern browsers, and also IE8.

Answer (score 0):

> I got multiple IDs I want to do the same stuff ...

When you here such a phrase, it can be a sign that you need to use classes. They are used exactly for this: to denote group of similar elements.

So what you should do is to add the same class to all elements, then select all necessary elements, and then use `for` loop to process all of them.

For example, HTML:

```
<input class="int" name="int" placeholder="40" type="number" min="0" max="100">
<input class="int-hard" name="int-hard" placeholder="20" type="number" min="0" max="100">
<input class="int-extr" name="int-extr" placeholder="6" type="number" min="0" max="100">
```

and then javascript:

```
var int = document.querySelectorAll('.int');

for (var i = 0; i < int; i++) {
    var hardRoll = int[i].value / 2;
    var extrRoll = int[i].value / 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
// Your inputs, selected by ID
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#int-hard, #int-extr");

// Apply onchange to selected input fields
for(var i = 0, length = inputs.length; i < length; i++) {
  inputs[i].onchange = function() {
    this.value = Math.floor(this.value);
  }; 
}
```

And please don't use `window.onchange` as this fires off to *every* change in your document.

Comment: Do you really have to extend a DOM data structure to solve this problem?

Comment: Of course not. You can use other ways to iterate through a NodeList. But since this runs once on page load, I don't see any impact on performance whatsoever.

Comment: My comment wasn't about performance.  It was about extending the DOM in non-standard ways (not considered a best practice) when it's not even remotely necessary.

Comment: OK, changed my answer. Now using a for loop.